# JQuery change atributes of child elements

Tags: jquery

I have this code, and  I want on click on div with `favoriteButton` class, text in current (`this`) `<a>` and `src` of current `img` tag to be changed.
Changing text in `<a>` work fine but image not work.
I try to put another  as child of first  and code work fine, only in nested `img` not work

```
$('.favoriteButton').click(function(e){

    $(this).find('.aclass').text("yeeee");
    $(this).find('.imgclass').attr("src", "remove_favorit.png");

    e.preventDefault(); 

});


    <div class="favoriteButton" >                                    
     <a class="aclass" href="">Text
       <img class="imgclass" src="add_heart.png">
     </a>
    </div>
    <div class="favoriteButton" >                                    
     <a class="aclass"  href="">Text
       <img class="imgclass" src="add_heart.png">
     </a>
     </div>
```

Can some one help me how to solve that using JQuery

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the image is inside the link, so when you change the `.text()` value of the link, the image disappears. To solve this, take the image outside of the link, or cache it and append it after you change the text.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(this).find('.imgclass img').attr("src", "remove_favorit.png");
```