# Change/Add the child of child's element <a>'s target attribute via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have a `<div>` like below

```
<div class="divClass">
<ul class="ulClass">
    <li id="liID" class="liClass">
        <a href="myLink">
        <span class="spanClass">myText</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Now I want to write a jQuery script to read the `<a>` element and set the value of target attribute to `_blank`.

I went through [JQuery change atributes of child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204209/jquery-change-atributes-of-child-elements) and got a script. But, it gave me a script like below

```
$('.divClass').click(function(e){

$(this).find('.aclass').text("yeeee");
$(this).find('.imgclass').attr("src", "remove_favorit.png");

e.preventDefault(); 

});
```

What I actually want is iterate through `<div>`, `<ul>`, `<li>` and then reach out to the `<a>` in it and set the `target`. How can I do this?

I also went through [Get attribute of child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740297/jquery-get-attribute-of-child-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't want it to happen on click but following code will set the `target=_blank` on clicking on a link inside `divClass`

```
$(function(){
    $('.divClass .ulClass .liClass').on('click', 'a', function(e){
        $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});​
```

And this code will do it on page load

```
$(function(){
    $('.divClass .ulClass liClass a').attr('target', '_blank');
});​
```

Comment: I tried yours in the fiddle link posted by stefanz. This works perfectly. But, since my reputation is low, I can't vote this up. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Check it here http://fiddle.jshell.net/MQfJM/

As you can see in image [image] this code adds a target blank to all elements from the page, when they're loaded.

Let say you want to add target="_blank" only to  from list. You only have to replace that

```
$('a') with $('ul a')
```

If you want to add target="_blank" when user clicks the anchor you can modify my code `$(document).ready(function(){ /* code */ })`
to looks like

```
$('a').on( 'click', function(){
   $(this).attr( 'target', '_blank' );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle link. It works. I tried there too. Sorry, I'm unable to vote this up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `$(".divClass > .ulClass > .liClass > a").attr("target", "_blank")`

It's a very specific selector, remove all '>' if you need to.